# Location of "network_security_config.xml" file in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Been trying to find out file named "network_security_config.xml" in flutter. I have no idea where to find it. I do not see any thread here. Sorry for the silly question but can anyone help me since I am going to implement appodeal plugin.

There is only one step which confusing.

**"In your network_security_config.xml file, add base-config that sets cleartextTrafficPermitted to true :"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Source: https://pub.dev/documentation/stack_appodeal_flutter/latest/

Comment: There wont be that file anywhere. You have to create it inside <Project Root Folder>/android/app/src/main/res/xml  folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `Network Security Configuration` file to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Put your XML configuration under `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`,

In your `network_security_config.xml` file, add `base-config` that sets `cleartextTrafficPermitted` to `true` :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```